# Returning ListView.Builder to IndexdedStack

Tags: flutter, dart

main.dart

```
.......
final _widgetOptions = [Post(), Cat(), Fav(), Editors()];
..........
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: IndexedStack(index: currentIndex, children: _widgetOptions), //so on
```

post.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Cat extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CatState createState() => _CatState();
}

class _CatState extends State<Cat> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("Latest Posts"),
    
    ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("DEMO DATA");
      },
      itemCount: 2,
    )
  ],
));
}
}
```

when i try to return a column with having children TEXT and ListView.builder the execution gets stop with error msg "
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#abd36 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'"

## Note: if i remove ListView.builder inside from the column  or I directly return ListView.builder then no error But i want to show a Text First then List Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this to solve your problem.

```
class Cat extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CatState createState() => _CatState();
}

class _CatState extends State<Cat> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("Latest Posts"),

    Expanded(
      child:ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("DEMO DATA");
      },
      itemCount: 100,
    )
    )
  ],
);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you but can i move the text latest posts to left or right align

Comment: yes ! uses crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start (column widget)